# Página com layout diferente

Tags: css, wordpress

Estou começando a desenvolver temas para o WordPress e até então consegui alguns conteudos e tutoriais de como fazer tal coisa, porém as informações que eu tenho são que:

- a página `page.php` é responsavel por exibir as páginas do site tais como `contato`,`quem somos` e etc
- e a página `single.php` é responsavel por exibir o conteudo dos pontos juntamente com a página `archive.php`.

Uma das duvidas é exatamente essa, qual o sistema de julgamento para o WordPress utilizar as páginas `single` e `archive`? A outra duvida é de como posso aplicar estilos diferentes para páginas diferentes? Se o conteudo das páginas `(contato, quem somos)` é exibida em `page.php` que contém apenas 1 estilo?

Comment: um pouco de ajuda você encontra http://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Hierarquia_de_Modelos_Wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de aplicar estilos individuais, por exemplo na página de Contato, é criar um template `page-contato.php`. O importante é o `slug` da página:

[image]

Se aquele `slug` fosse `sample-page`, o template teria que se chamar `page-sample-page.php`.

E, ao editar, faz as marcações de CSS necessárias nesse template personalizado.

---

Outra maneira muito simples é se você tiver o [**`body_class()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) aplicado no `<body>` do HTML. Isso fica no arquivo `header.php`:

```
</head>   
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="conteudo">
```

Com essa função aplicada no `<body>`, o HTML para a página de contato é o seguinte:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

E na sua folha de estilo, aplicaria regras do tipo:

```css
body.page-id-2 #conteudo { text-align: right }
```

Deste jeito pode personalizar praticamente todas as páginas, posts, categorias, etc.

---

Pode [conferir mais detalhes na documentação](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), que inclui este diagrama de como funciona a hierarquia de templates no WordPress:

[image: wordpress template hierarchy]

Comment: não entendi bem como funciona o `body_clas()`, conversei com alguns amigos e me disseram pra usar o mesmo `css` que vai no `header` e apenas acrescentar outros ids e outras classes, por exemplo.
Se em minha `index.php` eu tenho um `h1`com `color: blue` e em minha pagina de `contato`eu queira usar um `h1`  de novo porem com outra cor eu poderia fazer 2 classes no mesmo arquivo `style.css`, `h1-index {codigo}` e `h1-contato{codigo}`, o que voce acha?

Comment: Confere como as classes vão mudando no `body` conforme você navega pelo site

Comment: Se o theme é você quem está desenvolvendo, sim, pode modificar o CSS principal. Se o theme não é seu, o ideal é um child-theme, porque assim pode fazer updates no theme principal sem problemas. Como é a implementação no PHP desse `h1-index` e `h1-contato` que propõe? . . . O HTML que o `body_class()` imprime pode ser customizado, tem um filtro pra isso. O que proponho é que tenha no CSS: `body.index h1 {/*etc*/}` e `body.contato h1 {/*etc*/}`.

Comment: Se não customizar o `body_class()`, o CSS seria: `body.page-id-ID_DO_INDEX h1 {/*etc*/}` e `body.page-id-ID_DO_CONTATO h1 {/*etc*/}`.

Comment: O tema é meu mesmo, estou aprendendo a desenvolver sozinho.

Comment: Aqui tem uns código legais pra limpar o output do body_class: [Remove classes from body_class](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/15850/12615) . . . e pode usar algo como [`is_page('contato')`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) para colocar classes personalizadas

Answer (score 0):

Em relação ao critério... O ideal é você ler a [documentação de hierarquia no codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Hierarquia_de_Modelos_Wordpress).
Pra você criar estilos diferentes pra paginas você pode criar uma [Page Template.](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) 
Com ela você vai pode fazer estilos diferentes, ter singles diferente , archive, header, footer e etc. 
É idela você ver no codex sobre. 
E antes de você criar a Page Templete, o ideal é você ter bem claro na sua cabeça a hierarquia do WP ou tentar se guiar ao máximo por ela.
Pra não te trazer problema no futuro.
Espero ter ajudado.
 
Até mais.